# How can I run Mist as a Full Node?

Tags: nodes

I'm running Windows and have around 50-80GB that I can dedicate to running a full node until I add a Hard Drive in a couple of months. I have around 200-400 download/upload and a decent processor. I could install Geth but I want to run Mist instead as a full node. How should I do this?

Edit: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I already have Mist running and syncing but I want to run a full node to help the network and act as a peer.

Comment: Mist will use geth internally at its backend and will sync it for you.

Comment: @Rajesh does geth make my full node act as a peer (for uploading as well) by default?

Comment: Geth downloads full dbs to your system, and the transaction you send will be submitted to the network, and upon succesful mining, they will be displayed in your mist wallet too

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Mist is no longer an active project since 2019 (https://avsa.medium.com/sunsetting-mist-da21c8e943d2).

Answer (score 0):

Once you install Mist and run it, it will prompt you to create an account and then it will start syncing you will be able to see the process. When it finishes you'll be able to use Mist and you'll have a full node.

Comment: If I do this and leave Mist running is it already acting as a peer?

Comment: @rajlego That's a good question, I'm not too sure but I don't think you need to have a full node to be acting as a peer.

Comment: Do you know how much disk space Mist takes up once it is done syncing? If it is a full node I would assume it would be quite a lot.

Comment: @wuno it's about 40gb right now using the fast sync.

Comment: @CNuts thanks for getting back to me. Based on your answer, are you insinuating that Mist by default does a fast sync?

Comment: @wuno No mist doesn't do a fast sync by default but using the fast sync is way faster and takes less disk space.